# Understanding a real analysis proof and concept: If $A$ is compact subset of $X$, then $f(A)$ is a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

It seems to me that this proof does not prove "If $A$ is compact subset of $X$, then $f(A)$ is a compact set," but rather that statement: If $A\subset X$ is compact relative to $X$, then $f(A)$ is a compact set relative to $Y$. The cover $\{U_a\}$ of $f(A)$ is only required to be open relative to $Y$. The fact that $f$ is continuous only allows the conclusion that $f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open relative to $X$, not that $f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open in the context of the entire real line. Can you please help me flesh this out? I am having trouble grasping the subtleties.

Prior to this proof, the author gives a proof of the following fact: if a set is compact, then it is closed and bounded. But the proof the author gives is in the context of all of $\mathbb{R}$. Am I correct to believe that I cannot combine this fact with the previously discussed theorem to conclude $f(A)$ is closed and bounded? Can I really online conclude  $f(A)$ is closed and bounded relative to $Y$? What does it mean to have a set be bounded relative to another set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Heine-Borel theorem about closedness and boundedness refers to a subset being considered as closed in all of $\Bbb R$. Boundedness is what we might call “absolute”, since it is a property that is invariant under regarding the same set in different subspaces. For instance $(0,1)$ is not compact, yet it is a closed subspace of itself. The closedness *must* be considered in $\Bbb R$.

Very importantly, compactness is also absolute. Given a topological space $Z$ and any subspace $W$ of $Z$, a set $A\subset W$ is compact in $Z$ iff. it is compact in $W$. So when you write ‘compactness *relative* to…’, that relativity does not actually matter (but it *does* for many topological concepts, so beware!).

Compactness is absolute because:

> If $A$ is compact in $Z$, then it is compact in $W$. Proof: an open cover of $A$ in $W$ is precisely a cover of $A$ by sets $\{U_\alpha\cap W\}$ where the $U_\bullet$ are open in $Z$. But then $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $A$ in $Z$, so there is a finite subcover $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n. But $A\subset W$ means $$\{U_i\cap W\}_{i=1}^n$ is still an open cover of $A$ in $W$, and this is a finite subcover of the original cover. Thus $A$ is compact in $W$.

I recommend you prove the converse: that $A$’s compactness in $W$ implies its compactness in $Z$.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, but I feel like this doesn't address a lot of my post. It seems to me that this proof does not prove "If $A$ is compact subset of $X$, then $f(A)$ is a compact set," but rather that statement: If $A\subset X$ is compact relative to $X$, then $f(A)$ is a compact set relative to $Y$.

Comment: To be compact, we require that every open cover have a finite sub cover. But this proof only shows that every open cover of $f(A)$ relative to Y has an finite subcover, with each set only required to be open relative to $Y$

Comment: @peanut That’s exactly what I’ve addressed, but maybe I phrased it confusingly. $A\subset X$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $A$ is compact relative to $\Bbb R$, that is, closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$. Similarly for $f(A)$. So you can think of the theorem as this; a subset of $\Bbb R$ that is closed and bounded will have closed and bounded image under any continuous function. That’s more-or-less the extreme value theorem! Phrasing it in terms of compactness is more general, though

Comment: No, I take it back. you gave me exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't understand, and with this comment everything is coming together. Thanks. I accept as best answer.

Comment: So I showed that $A$ is compact in $\Bbb R$ implies $A$ is compact in $X$, and I also showed that $f(A)$ is compact in $\Bbb R$ implies it is compact in $Y$. I encourage you to essentially copy the proof to prove the reverse implications

Comment: You did great. Thanks. this made a big difference.

Comment: @peanut No problem, you’re welcome. If you’re interested there is a general Heine-Borel theorem for metric spaces; a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete (all Cauchy sequences converge) and totally bounded (can be covered with finitely many balls of small radius). As $\Bbb R$ is complete, any closed subset of $\Bbb R$ is complete (iff.). And any bounded set in $\Bbb R$ is totally bounded! Hence the normal Heine-Borel